# What's a single word for the context a word is used in (used to differentiate similar words)?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I saw a question on this site asking about the difference between two similar words and one of the answers said it was the specific context each word was used in, except they used a single word that meant that.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question you are talking about?

Comment: I saw it months ago so I don't remember. If I did, I'd have looked for it.

Comment: Are you talking about homonyms? (e.g. bow [and arrow] and bow [to bow down to someone])

Comment: Nope, words that are different but have similar meanings, like what you'd find in a thesaurus. Even if they're listed as similar words they've got different nuances and are used differently. I'm looking for the word referring to how they're used differently.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for *connotation*?  Two words with similar meanings can have slightly different connotations, and this difference sometimes depends on the context.

Comment: You might be asking for "sense" also. It is the meaning of a word, especially within a context.

Comment: It can be argued that the same word has different nuances in all the different contexts in which it appears. Indeed, the nuances picked up on by two different readers will differ even for the same context. Someone somewhere has said 'All words are infinitely polysemic.'

Comment: Are you just looking for "interpretation"?  So, as Edwin says just above this, "everything is open to interpretation", or "what was your interpretation?" or "how do you interpret what Mom said?" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be  referring to [contextualization:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contextualization)

To contextualize:

> - to place  (a word or idea, for example) in a particular context.
> - to put (a linguistic element, an action, etc.) in a context, esp. one that is characteristic or appropriate, as for purposes of study.

Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

The generic single word you are looking for is "context".

It sounds like you are looking for a more specific word, which describes the particular context which is normally found around a particular word. In the sentences:

> The stone was too *hard* to break
>
> The pear was too *hard* to eat

What you are looking for is a word which describes "stone too __ to break" and "pear too __ to eat".

This would distinguish *hard* from other uses of *hard*, such as

> I failed the exam because it was *hard*

In Natural Language Processing (NLP), this relationship is referred to as [lexical co-occurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence). It would follow that the context itself would be referred to as "lexical co-occurrers". However, this term is not used in in NLP. Instead, the context around a word is referred to simply as **context** or **lexical context**.